# True/False in PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

Can someone help me how to change the **bool** type in phpmyadmin(interface).

e.g. 
If you click button number 1, it says true and if you click button number 2 it says false.

Comment: Are you taking about the phpmyadmin interface, the data in your DB, or the structure of your DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE `table`.`col` SET `value` = b'1';
```

Comment: If you want to change boolean from false to true, you apply the `b` before the value. I don't know the exact meaning, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make an update statement like Eda said. To clarify, if the table is called Test and the column is called Information, the statement would read:

UPDATE Test.Information SET value = b'1'